# ServerSocket in Worker throws SecurityError

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a Worker which attempts to create a ServerSocket and bind it, yet throws an error. Here's the relevant code in the Worker:

```
try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, socketConnectHandler);

                serverSocket.bind(port, "127.0.0.1");
                serverSocket.listen();
            }
            catch (error:Error) { ... }
```

The error is:

> SecurityError: Error #3205: Only application-sandbox content can
>   access this feature.

Is there any way to allow this? It is an AIR application

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the solution is in passing "true" as second parameter to WorkerDomain.current.createWorker();